# Inheriting from "str" class

Tags: python, inheritance, operator-overloading

I'm doing this little exercise...
I want to reorder a string based on some weird dictionary.
For example, according to my dictionary, the letters come in the order: 
"a", "b", "d", "c", "f", "e"

So I figured I should just overload the < operator for strings and call sorted()

Here goes:

```
class MyString(str):
     new_dict = dict((x,i) for i,x in enumerate(["a", "b", "d", "c", "f", "e"]))
     def __lt__(self,other):
         return self.new_dict[self] < self.new_dict[other]
     def __init__(self,x):
         str.__init__(self,x)
```

And then

```
In [59]: sorted((MyString(x) for x in "abcdef"))
Out[59]: ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']
```

That's awesome. Or even:

```
In [64]: MyString("".join(sorted((MyString(x) for x in "abcdef"))))
Out[64]: 'abdcfe'
```

But why can't I just do `sorted(MyString("abcdef"))`?

```
In [70]: sorted(MyString("abcdef"))
Out[70]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Apparently the iterator of MyString is returning strings.

```
In [72]: for i in MyString("abcdef"):
             print type(i)
      ....:     
      <type 'str'>
      <type 'str'>
      <type 'str'>
      <type 'str'>
      <type 'str'>
      <type 'str'>
```

What happens if I call join on MyString:

```
In [63]: type(MyString("").join(sorted((MyString(x) for x in "abcdef"))))
Out[63]: str
```

Why does MyString have str iterators?

Comment: `sorted()` takes a key function letting you define a sort value to sorted elements instead.

Comment: Otherwise, sorting uses `>`, `>=`, `<=` and `==` as well, you need to provide *all* operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the [`__getitem__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) here:

```
class MyString(str):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return type(self)(super(MyString, self).__getitem__(i))
```

This returns a new instance of the current type:

```
>>> for i in MyString("abcdef"):
...     print type(i)
... 
<class '__main__.MyString'>
<class '__main__.MyString'>
<class '__main__.MyString'>
<class '__main__.MyString'>
<class '__main__.MyString'>
<class '__main__.MyString'>
```

`str` itself doesn't implement iteration (it has no [`__iter__` menthod](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__), but *does* implement the sequence protocol (it has both a `__len__` length method an a `__getitem__` method); it is this that the `for` loop ultimately uses).

If using Python 3, the `str` object *does* have a `__iter__` method and you need to override that instead:

```
class MyString(str):
    def __iter__(self):
        return (type(self)(i) for i in super().__iter__())
```

Note that `str` is an immutable type, overriding `__init__` has little influence on the instance.

For ordering, you really need to implement all of the `__gt__`, `__ge__`, `__eq__`, etc. methods too. Use the [`@functools.total_ordering()` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to save yourself most of the work here:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class MyString(str):
    sortmap = {x: i for i, x in enumerate("abdcfe")}

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.sortmap[self] < self.sortmap[other]

    # inherit __eq__ from str

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return type(self)(super(MyString, self).__getitem__(i))
```

Last but not least, for sorting, just use the `key` argument to `sorted()` here:

```
>>> sortmap = {x: i for i, x in enumerate("abdcfe")}
>>> sorted('abcdef', key=sortmap.get)
['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']
```

Comment: So anything that inherits from immutable classes will be immutable? And anything that inherits from mutable will be mutable? Is there a way to change that? Just curious.

Comment: @Diana: No, that's not it, really. You cannot alter the immutable component (the `str` value) but you can alter additional attributes you give your subclass. However, you don't do that in your class, so the `__init__` has no real value.

Comment: So with `__getitem__` overloaded, why is `type(MyString("").join(MyString("123")))` still `str`?

Comment: @Diana: You'll need to override the `str.join()` method for that. It returns a regular string still.

Answer (score 0):

You don need a subclass for customizing sort behavior - 
you can pass a `key` parameter to a `sort` method or `sorted` call, specifying a function
that gives the relative weights of each element being compared.

Like in:

def mycomp(text):
    myseq = ("abdcfe")
    weigthed = [myseq.find(char) for char in text]
    return weigthed  # this will place -1's for chars not found in your mapping string

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use the `key` parameter instead of your approach. The reason it is not working however is simply that you didn't overload the `__iter__` function:

```
class MyString(str):
    # ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for x in super().__iter__():
            yield self.__class__(x)
```

In Python 2 you can use

```
class MyString(str):
    # ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for x in super(MyString, self).__str__():
            yield self.__class__(x)
```

Comment: This only works in Python 3; Python 2 `str.__iter__` doesn't exist.